# Tests cases for merge in merge sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge

Are there any edge cases or just cases in general that I need to test for this function. The only thing I can think of is if one of the arrays being merged is empty. Are there other test cases I need to consider?

Comment: Of course there's always the extreme case that no sane person covers and that is when there are so many files to merge you cannot open them all at once.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon who's talking about file merge? It's the `merge` part of the [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Good point - file sorts are often forgotten. In fact, whether it is a file or data sort is often your starting point for choosing a sort algorithm based on the comparison/move overheads.

Answer (score 7):

For any sort, I consider these cases:

- The empty list
- An already sorted list
- A reverse sorted list
- A list consisting of the same element throughout
- A list containing dupes

This is not just to prove the algorithm but also for performance.

Answer (score 4):

Following cases I used to test my Merge Sort code. I guess this covers majority of the cases. You can directly copy in your C code and use it for testing.

```
//int arr[] = {12, 15, 23, 4 , 6, 10, 35, 28}; //Even number of element
//int arr[]={}; //Empty list 
int *arr = NULL; //Null pointer
//int arr[] = {4, 6, 10, 12, 15, 23, 28, 35}; //already sorted array
//int arr[] = {12, 15, 23, 4 , 6, 10, 35}; //odd length array
//int arr[] = {35, 28, 23, 15, 12, 10, 6, 4}; //descending sorted array input
//int arr[] = {12};//one element
//int arr[] = {12, 4}; // two elements
//int arr[] = {12, 15, 23, 4 , 6, 10, 35, 28, 100, 130, 500, 1000, 235, 554, 75, 345, 800, 222, 333, 888, 444, 111, 666, 777, 60};//large list of elements 
//int arr[] = {12, 15, -23, -4 , 6, 10, -35, 28}; //negative elements
int arr[] = {12, 12, 23, 4 , 6, 6, 10, -35, 28}; //duplicate elements
int arr[] = {12, 12, 12, 12, 12}; //Same element
```

Answer (score 3):

Some more:

- Think about the number of elements in each array:
  Both array have even number of elements
  One array has even while the other has odd number of elements
  Number of elements in one array is more than the number of elements in another
- Also consider the range of elements in the array
  The largest element in one array is smaller than the smallest element in the second array
  One array has duplicates
  Both the arrays have the same set of elements e.g.(A1: 2,4,6,8 and A2: 2,4,6,8)

Basically these ones are good at catching one off errors in the for loop while merging

Answer (score 1):

Think about every `if` statement and loop condition in your code and try to find test cases which would make the condition true/false. If you post your code we can discuss possible test cases.